# How do I form a Django query with an arbitrary number of OR clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, python-3.x, contains

I'm using Django 2.0 with Python 3.7.  I want to write a query that returns results if the fields contains at least one of the strings in an array, so I want to set up an OR query.  I have tried this

```
class CoopManager(models.Manager):
    ...
    # Meant to look up coops case-insensitively by part of a type
    def contains_type(self, types_arr):
        queryset = Coop.objects.all()
        for type in types_arr:
            queryset = queryset.filter(type__name__icontains=type)
        print(queryset.query)
        return queryset
```

However, this produces a query that ANDs the clauses together.  How do I perform the above but join all the clauses with an OR instead of an AND?

I'm using MySql 5.7 but I'd like to know a db independent solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Q` object that constructs this disjunction:

```
from django.db.models import Q

filter = Q(
    *[('type__name__icontains', type) for type in types_arr],
    _connector=Q.OR
)
queryset = Coop.objects.filter(filter)
```

Here `filter` is a `Q` object that is a disjunction of all the `type__name__icontains=type` filters.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I should have mentioned in my question taht "types_arr" is a list of Strings.  You may have already assumed that in your answer, but I'm getting a "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'" error on the 'queryset = Coop.objects.filter(filter)' line.

Comment: @Dave: no, I made a typo, it is with an asterisk (`*`) before the list comprehension.